# How to generate an independent makefile from Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have created a project using Eclipse CDT on an ARM. Many settings have been changed through out the Eclipse. Include directories, Compiler options, etc...

I need to generate a makefile that is capable to generate the excutable from the command line.

I have noticed that in the Debug directory there are several files:

`makefile`, `objects.mk`, `sources.mk`, `subdir.mk`

In each directory inside Debug there is also a `subdir.mk` file
So everything seems to be in place. It is a bit inconvenient to have so many files. I would prefer to have just one, since it is generated automatically.
Nevertheless when I try to use makefile I get an error:

```
[user@athena VDIU]$ make -f Debug/makefile
    Building target: VDIU.elf
    Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Linker
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -Xlinker --gc-sections -Xlinker --script="../../../config/linker-script-flash.ld" -Wl,-Map,"VDIU.map" -o "VDIU.elf"   
    /bin/sh: arm-none-eabi-gcc: command not found
    Debug/makefile:64: recipe for target 'VDIU.elf' failed
    make: *** [VDIU.elf] Error 127
```

It seems to complain about **arm-none-eabi-gcc** although when compiled in Eclipse all is well. (The compilation console output in Eclipse is quite big but I show below one of the files only)

```
Building file: ../VDIU_main.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -D__SAME70Q21__ -D__FREERTOS__ -DARM_MATH_CM7=true -DBOARD=SAME70_XPLAINED -DDEBUG -Dprintf=iprintf -I../../../ -I../../../config -I../../../board -I../../../ASF -I../../../ASF/sam/boards -I../../../ASF/sam/boards/same70_xplained -I../../../ASF/sam/drivers/uart -I../../../ASF/sam/drivers/mpu -I../../../ASF/sam/drivers/pio -I../../../ASF/sam/drivers/usart -I../../../ASF/sam/drivers/pmc -I../../../ASF/sam/drivers/twihs -I../../../ASF/sam/utils -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/header_files -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/preprocessor -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/fpu -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/cmsis/same70/include/component -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/cmsis/same70/include -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/cmsis/same70/include/instance -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/cmsis/same70/include/pio -I../../../ASF/sam/utils/cmsis/same70/source/templates -I../../../ASF/common/utils -I../../../ASF/common/utils/interrupt -I../../../ASF/common/utils/stdio/stdio_serial -I../../../ASF/common/services/clock -I../../../ASF/common/services/clock/same70 -I../../../ASF/common/services/ioport -I../../../ASF/common/services/ioport/sam -I../../../ASF/common/services/serial -I../../../ASF/common/services/serial/sam_uart -I../../../ASF/common/services/gpio -I../../../ASF/common/services/gpio/sam_gpio -I../../../ASF/common/boards -I../../../ASF/thirdparty/freertos/freertos-10.0.0/Source/include -I../../../ASF/thirdparty/freertos/freertos-10.0.0/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1 -I../../../ASF/thirdparty/freertos/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/include -I../../../ASF/thirdparty/freertos/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/source/portable/Compiler/GCC -I../../../ASF/thirdparty/freertos/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/source/portable/NetworkInterface/include -I../../../ASF/thirdparty/freertos/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/source/portable/NetworkInterface/DriverSAM -I../../../ASF/thirdparty/CMSIS/Include -std=gnu11 -g -MMD -MP -MF"VDIU_main.d" -MT"VDIU_main.o" -c -o "VDIU_main.o" "../VDIU_main.c"
Finished building: ../VDIU_main.c
```

Comment: Not really a C question.

Comment: arm-none-eabi-gcc is not on your PATH variable. Eclipse will set that path based on the toolset selected.

Comment: Shouldn't the PATH variable be set on the makefile? If it is not then the makefile can never be run on its own... Is there another file that can be created by Eclipse that evokes the make after setting properly all the environment variables?